# Twitter api php foreach loop not working for users tweets

Tags: php, twitter, tweets, tweetstream

I am using the twitter api php abraham libary and i am trying to loop through the users tweets, but i am having trouble.

I am getting all the users tweets from the home timeline using this.

```
$content = $connection->get('statuses/home_timeline');

echo '<pre>',print_r($content),'</pre>';
```

If i print out the array...i get this.

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object (    [created_at] => Tue Feb 10 15:31:07 +0000 2015 [id] => 565171109470171136 [id_str] => 565171109470171136 [text] => We are human beings not human doings – let’s start acting like it & take the time simply to be http://t.co/i4HAnApQxp http://t.co/3qSXA4D1qY [source] => Hootsuite [truncated] => [in_reply_to_status_id] => [in_reply_to_status_id_str] => [in_reply_to_user_id] => [in_reply_to_user_id_str] => [in_reply_to_screen_name] => [user] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 8161232 [id_str] => 8161232 [name] => Richard Branson [screen_name] => richardbranson [location] => [profile_location] => [description] => Tie-loathing adventurer, philanthropist & troublemaker, who believes in turning ideas into reality. Otherwise known as Dr Yes at @virgin! [url] => http://t.co/pWM2y98gTu [entities] => stdClass Object (
```

How would i get the name from the std class object using a forech loop?

I have tryed this but it is not working??

```
foreach($content['user'] as $tweets) {
echo $tweets['name'] . '<br />';

}
```

Any help would be good :)

Answer (score 2):

Ok this seemed to work ..thank you for your help

```
foreach($content as $tweets) {

echo $tweets->user->name . '<br />';

echo $tweets->text . '<br />';

}
```

Answer (score 0):

what you need to do is this;

```
foreach($content as $tweets) {
    foreach($tweets['user'] as $user) {
        echo $user['name'] . '<br />';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you ...but i just tried that and it didnt work :(.....i need to loop [created_at] [text] and user->[name] ....because it is a stdclass object do i need to loop the $key value ?? If so how would i do this?? :(